# Create akka actor on remote node without using router

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster, akka-remote-actor, akka-remoting

I am working on one application which demands for akka clustering.
I am able to create akka cluster and create actors and pass them messages.

Following is my configuration:

```
relay.system {
    akka {
      loglevel = "INFO"
      actor {
        provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
      }
      remote {
        log-remote-lifecycle-events = on
        netty.tcp {
          hostname = "vm1.iviws.local"
          port = 3503
        }
      }
      cluster {
        seed-nodes = [
          "akka.tcp://RelaySystem@vm1.iviws.local:3503"
          "akka.tcp://RelaySystem@vm2.iviws.local:3503"
        ]
        auto-down-unreachable-after = 30s
      }
    }
}
```

Following is sample code with which I am able to create actors on remote node.

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory    
val config = ConfigFactory.load    
val akkaConfig = config.getConfig("relay.system")    
val actorSystem = ActorSystem("RelaySystem", akkaConfig)    
val roundRobinPool = RoundRobinPool(nrOfInstances = 4)    
val clusterRouterSettings = ClusterRouterPoolSettings(totalInstances = 4, maxInstancesPerNode = 2, allowLocalRoutees = true, useRole = None)    
val clusterRouterPool = ClusterRouterPool(roundRobinPool, clusterRouterSettings)    
val router = actorSystem.actorOf(clusterRouterPool.props(Props[Logger]))
```

Above code creates remote actor with help of router.

If I try to create actor without help of router: `val actorA = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Logger])`
Then actor is created on my local system.

Is there any way to create actors on remote node without using router or without telling remote node where I want to create actor?

Basically what I want is: `val actorA = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Logger])` should create actor on any random node in cluster(including local node).

Comment: If you only want a single instance of this actor, then perhaps what you want is a Cluster Singleton and should investigate the documentation for that feature: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/cluster-singleton.html

Comment: RouterGroup  instead of RouterPool , look the docs: [http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/cluster-usage.html#Cluster_Aware_Routers]

Comment: Why do you not want to use a Router? What you are expecting is exactly what RandomPool does. Are you facing any problem in using that?

Comment: I just need to create actor on random nodes. My actors are communicating to web client(1 actor per one client) and there is dedicated channel between actor and client. So I am preferring not to use routers and create actors with actorOf method directly.